# ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I am new to iPhone development. My app will call a web service running in apache tomcat. 
http://localhost:8080/myApp/WebservicePathName

Following are the code which calls my REST web-service:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *req;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/myApp/WebservicePathName"];
        req = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [req setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
        [req setDelegate:self];
        [req setTimeOutSeconds:10000];
        [req setDidFailSelector:@selector(eventUploadFailed:)];
        [req setDidFinishSelector:@selector(eventUploadFinished:)];
        [req appendPostData:[myString  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
        [req startSynchronous];

My web service code will be as:
@Path("/WebservicePathName")
@POST
public String post(String theString)
    {
        return theString;
    }
```

When I run the code in iPhone, in  `[req startSynchronous]`, I get an error in console like:

> ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred"
>   UserInfo=0x1664a0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1b2130 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. Operation timed out", NSLocalizedDescription=A
>   connection failure occurred}

Can anyone say whats wrong in it. whether the problem is with webservice call or response.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try by remplacing localhost by the IP address of the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Already I tried with my IP address, but the same error displays..

Comment: yes.. I have not use the above address. I have used my machine IP address..